# Setting columnTypes in ag-grid

Tags: reactjs, types, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm trying to figure out how to get ag-grid working with Typescript React. I'm trying to make a table with a custom column type. The custom column type and the default column type I'm defining don't seem to be working and I'm not sure why. Here's a simple version of my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { AgGridReact } from 'ag-grid-react';
import { GridOptions } from "ag-grid-community";
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css';
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css';


class App extends React.Component<{}, GridOptions> {
  constructor(props: GridOptions) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      rowData: [
        {foo: 1, bar: 'abc'},
        {foo: 2, bar: 'def'},
      ],
      columnDefs: [
        {headerName: "foo", field: "foo", type: "numberColumn"}, 
        {headerName: "bar", field: "bar"},
      ],
      defaultColDef: {
        width: 150,
        editable: true,
        sortable: true,
        filter: "agTextColumnFilter"
      },
      columnTypes: {
        "numberColumn": {
          width: 20,
          filter: "agNumberColumnFilter"
        },
      },
      onCellClicked: function(event) {window.alert('a row was clicked '+ event.data)},
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        className="ag-theme-balham"
        style={{
        height: '1000px',
        width: '6000px' }}
      >
        <AgGridReact
          columnDefs={this.state.columnDefs}
          rowData={this.state.rowData}>
        </AgGridReact>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I also found that `onCellClicked` isn't actually doing anything, so I think I'm misunderstanding something there.

Answer (score 1):

You are defining in your local state but you are not passing it to `AgGridReact` component this it has no knowledge of it.

You can destructure state properties like below:

```
    const {columnDefs, rowData, defaultColDef, onCellClicked, columnTypes} = this.state
```

And then use it and pass it like below:

```
    <AgGridReact
      columnDefs={columnDefs}
      rowData={rowData}
      defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
      onCellClicked={onCellClicked}
      columnTypes={columnTypes}
    >
    </AgGridReact>
```